# MacOS Dock remains visible in fullscreen

Tags: macos, mojave, dock, mission-control, fullscreen

I'm trying to solve a problem that's been bothering me for at least a couple of years: MacOS dock remains visible in fullscreen apps.

After switching to a fullscreen-mode app Dock won't disappear from time to time. It does not matter how to switch: by Mission Control with trackpad, by Mission Control with keyboard shortcut, switching directly between spaces with swipe or keyboard. Fullscreen-app doesn't matter either: it happens with Safari, Finder, Mail, ForkLift - just any app.

Dock then can be hidden with (1) pointing the cursor on it or (2) briefly engaging Mission Control with four-finger swipe or (3) half-switching to one of the desktops and back.

It looks like this.

[image: MacOS dock visible in fullscreen app]

Deleting `com.apple.Dock.plist`, enabling and disabling auto hide, dragging the Dock to left or right doesn't help. `killall Dock` won't help either.

Dock's log `log stream --predicate '(process == "Dock")' --debug` displays some issues which I can't solve.

Every Mission Control launch is accompanied with the following log output:

```
svintuss@svinbookpro ~ $ log stream --predicate '(process == "Dock")' --debug
Filtering the log data using "process == "Dock""
Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    TTL 
2020-05-14 17:50:45.831493+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] CFPrefsManagedSource<0x600002f28380> (Domain: kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No) loaded: an empty base plist and no additional changes from the base plist
2020-05-14 17:50:45.831569+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600002f283f0> (Domain: kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No) loaded: a new base plist and no additional changes from the base plist
2020-05-14 17:50:45.831606+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600002f28460> (Domain: kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No) loaded: a new base plist and no additional changes from the base plist
2020-05-14 17:50:45.831753+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] found no value for key bristol in CFPrefsSearchListSource<0x600002a28000> (Domain: com.apple.universalaccess, Container: (null))
2020-05-14 17:50:45.831869+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] found no value for key bristol in CFPrefsSearchListSource<0x600002a28000> (Domain: com.apple.universalaccess, Container: (null))
2020-05-14 17:50:45.832094+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] found no value for key bristol in CFPrefsSearchListSource<0x600002a28000> (Domain: com.apple.universalaccess, Container: (null))
2020-05-14 17:50:45.832180+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] found no value for key bristol in CFPrefsSearchListSource<0x600002a28000> (Domain: com.apple.universalaccess, Container: (null))
2020-05-14 17:50:45.832390+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] found no value for key bristol in CFPrefsSearchListSource<0x600002a28000> (Domain: com.apple.universalaccess, Container: (null))
2020-05-14 17:50:45.832474+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] found no value for key bristol in CFPrefsSearchListSource<0x600002a28000> (Domain: com.apple.universalaccess, Container: (null))
2020-05-14 17:50:45.832924+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFBundle:strings] Bundle: <private>, key: DesktopNum, value: , table: Localizable, localizationName: (null), result: Desktop %@
2020-05-14 17:50:45.833258+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFBundle:strings] Bundle: <private>, key: DesktopNum, value: , table: Localizable, localizationName: (null), result: Desktop %@
2020-05-14 17:50:45.833667+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] found no value for key com.apple.springing.delay in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600002f28310> (Domain: com.apple.dock, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No)
2020-05-14 17:50:45.837438+0300 0x192c2    Info        0x0                  327    0    Dock: (libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib) domain com.apple.dock.missioncontrol.shown is NOT on the whitelist AND device is NOT internal. Message will be dropped
2020-05-14 17:50:47.461262+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (LaunchServices) [com.apple.launchservices:cas] Getting process information for [ 0x0/0x9009]  from shared memory failed, so asking server for it
2020-05-14 17:50:47.461342+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (LaunchServices) [com.apple.launchservices:cas] sending={asn=36873U, restrictto=["LSStoppedState","LSIsProxiedForTAL"], command=360, }
2020-05-14 17:50:47.461695+0300 0x875      Debug       0x0                  327    0    Dock: (LaunchServices) [com.apple.launchservices:cas]  reply={result={LSIsProxiedForTAL=false, }, success=true, cacheable=false, }
2020-05-14 17:50:47.461774+0300 0x875      Info        0x0                  327    0    Dock: SelectWindow psn=(0x0 0x9009) wid=0x6e autoquit=0
```

Mission control launch on another Mac produces no log messages.

Could anyone explain what these errors mean? And how to fix them?

(1) `found no value for key bristol`. I tried creating one with `defaults write -globalDomain  bristol -bool true`, but it didn't change the output significantly. Maybe because it's waiting for another value.
Could someone post an example output of `defaults find bristol` command?

```
2020-05-14 18:16:28.405925+0300 0x1c477    Debug       0x0                  3822   0    Dock: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:User Defaults] looked up value <private> for key bristol in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600000845650> (Domain: kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No) via CFPrefsSearchListSource<0x600000d48880> (Domain: com.apple.universalaccess, Container: (null))
```

(2) `found no value for key com.apple.springing.delay`. But I do have this value set in NSGlobalDomain:

```
svintuss@svinbookpro ~ $ defaults read -globalDomain
    ...
    "com.apple.springing.delay" = "0.5";
    "com.apple.springing.enabled" = 1;
    ...
```

(3) `domain com.apple.dock.missioncontrol.shown is NOT on the whitelist AND device is NOT internal`. How can I look into this whitelist?

Comment: It appears that the aforementioned log output is irrelevant to the non-hiding Dock problem. I've got the same output on a fresh install of Mojave. 
The number of `found no value for key bristol` varies depending on the number of Safari windows open.

Still, did anyone experience this erratic Dock behaviour and was able to fix it?